# error CS1503: Argument 1 : cannot convert from 'method group' to 'strint' помогите пж юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
    
public class Loading : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int sceneID;
    
    public Slider loadSlider;
    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoadNextScene);
    }
    
    IEnumerator LoadNextScene()
    {
        AsyncOperation oper = Application.LoadLevelAsync(sceneID);
        while (!oper.isDone)
        {
            float progress = oper.progress / 0.9f;
            loadSlider.value = progress;
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

ошибка помогите пж

Comment: `StartCoroutine` принимает `IEnumerator`, по этому вам стоит передавать не метод `LoadNextScene`, а его вызов: `LoadNextScene()`

Answer (score 2):

Надо писать либо

```
StartCoroutine(LoadNextScene());
```

Либо

```
StartCoroutine("LoadNextScene");
```

Смотри доки https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html

Comment: стоит заметить, что хоть и оба варианта возможны, желательно всегда пользоваться первым, так как при изменениях метода, которые влекут изменении его сигнатуры, можно будет сразу узнать об ошибке вызова на этапе компиляции, а не на этапе выполнения